# django templateView compare permission

Tags: django, permissions

I am trying to check if account settings view, and username is a superuser then render the html. if not goes to error 403 , but how can I do this using templateview

```
class AccountSettingsView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profile/account-settings.html'
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        # error 403
    else:
        template_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`UserPassesTestMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) for that, and then override the [**`test_func(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin.test_func):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class AccountSettingsView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profile/account-settings.html'

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `dispatch` method and check that condition there:

```
class AccountSettingsView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profile/account-settings.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            # raise 403
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: if it doesn't find a user with the right permissions then will raise the error, does it?